# Torus Killing vectors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, differential-topology

I'm trying to calculate the Killing vectors associated to a 2D torus, parametrised as $ds^2=a^2d\theta^2+(b+a\sin\theta)^2d\phi^2$. From here I got the metric and found out that the only connection coefficients that don't vanish are:

$$ \Gamma^\theta{}_{\phi\phi}=-\frac{(b+a\sin\theta)\cos\theta}{a} \hspace{1cm}\Gamma^\phi{}_{\theta\phi}=\Gamma^\phi{}_{\phi\theta}=\frac{a\cos\theta}{b+a\sin{\theta}}$$

From here, and given the Killing condition: $\nabla_\alpha \xi_\beta + \nabla_\beta \xi_\alpha =\partial_\alpha \xi_\beta + \partial_\beta \xi_\alpha-2\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\beta\alpha}\xi_\lambda=0$, one can get the three following equations for the killing vectors:

$$\partial_\phi \xi_\phi = \Gamma^\theta{}_{\phi\phi}\xi_\theta=-\frac{(b+a\sin\theta)\cos\theta}{a}\xi_\theta \hspace{2cm} (1)$$
$$\partial_\phi \xi_\theta + \partial_\theta \xi_\phi = \frac{2a\cos\theta}{b+a\sin{\theta}}\xi_\phi \hspace{2cm} (2)$$
$$ 2\partial_\theta \xi_\theta=0 \hspace{2cm} (3)$$

From (3) it's easy to see that $\xi_\theta=f(\phi)$, so that (1) can be solved as:

$$\xi_\phi = -\frac{(b+a\sin\theta)\cos\theta}{a}F(\phi)+g(\theta),$$
with $F'(\phi)=f(\phi)$. This way, one can substitute in (2) and get the following differential equation:

$$f'(\phi)+[-\cos(2\theta) + \frac{b}{a}\sin\theta]F(\phi)=- \frac{2a\cos\theta}{b+a\sin\theta}g(\theta)-g'(\theta)$$

But I can't see how to solve this (could be that my differential equation solving skills aren't pretty much on point though... If only I could separate variables), and wouldn't like to spend too much time on it since it could also be that I made some mistake in the previous calculations, so if anyone sees something wrong (or that I'm on the good way), any feedback will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Look at your "final differential equation". Take derivative w.r.t. $\phi$. The RHS vanishes. The LHS becomes

$$ f''(\phi) - (\cos(2\theta) - \frac{b}{a} \sin\theta ) f(\phi) = 0.$$

Taking now the $\theta$ derivative, you find
$$ \left( 2 \sin(2 \theta) + \frac{b}{a} \cos(\theta) \right) f(\phi) = 0 $$

This equation is required to hold everywhere, and specifically when $\theta = 0$, which requires $f \equiv 0$. (In the case where $b = 0$ you no longer have a torus, and you do have other solutions!)

Plugging this into (1) you find that $\xi_\phi = h(\theta)$.
And plugging this into (2) you find that

$$ h' = \frac{2a \cos\theta}{b + a\sin\theta} h $$

which is a separable ODE which you easily solve to find

$$ h(\theta) = C (b+a\sin\theta)^2 $$

So in conclusion:

the only Killing vector field of the 2D torus is the obvious one, corresponding to $\partial_\phi$.

Comment: Thanks, let me fix that.