# Does $f''(\phi)+\left[1-\frac{b}{a}\sin\theta\right]f(\phi)=- \frac{2a\cos\theta}{b+a\sin\theta}g(\theta)-g'(\theta)$ have an "easy" solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As the years go by, my differential equation solving skills go down, and doing some physics exercises I found this differential equation that I've been stuck with for some time, which I have to solve for $f$ and $g$:

$$f''(\phi)+\left[1-\frac{b}{a}sin\theta\right]f(\phi)=- \frac{2acos\theta}{b+asin\theta}g(\theta)-g'(\theta)$$

Clearly, it would be easy to solve if that $-\frac{b}{a}sin\theta$ term wasn't there, cause I could have then just equated each side to a constant... But I don't know what to do with that one there.

If anyone is interested where this equation comes from, check out this other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4072272/torus-killing-vectors) of mine, where the steps to get it are specified (though I also checked my calculations a good bunch of times to make sure that's the definitive equation).

Comment: What is the relation between $f(\phi)$ and $F(\phi)$, or is $F$ a misprint for $f$?

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to specify that $F'(\phi)=f(\phi)$, I edited it.

Comment: Are you solving for $f$ and $g$ here? Or is one assumed known?

Comment: Yes, I'm solving for both of them, I re-edited the question to avoid that misunderstanding

Comment: How can you solve for both of them? Isn't it the case that for any arbitrary $g$ there is an $f$?

Comment: Well my professor solved an almost identical equation without the $-\frac{b}{a}sin\theta$ term and with a different factor (but still depending on $\theta$) multiplying $g(\theta)$, so I assumed this one must be solvable too, at least by imposing some conditions over the $f$ and $g$ functions (still, he got a pretty defined shape for both of them)

Comment: The right hand side does not depend on $\phi$ while the left hand side do so it has to be a constant. For the left hand side not to depend on $\theta$ we must have $f \equiv 0$. So you are left with the RHS equal to zero which gives $\frac{d}{d\theta}(g(a\sin(\theta) + b)^2) = 0$ or $g = \frac{C}{(a\sin(\theta) + b)^2}$.